# HTML a tag - href path to XML file open new tab in IE and safari

Tags: html, xml, internet-explorer, hyperlink, safari

I have this line in my HTML:

```
<a href="test.xml" target="_blank">Click here</a>
```

When the user click:

- In safari/IE: the xml file opened in new tab (undesirable behavior)
- In other browsers: the XML file is download to the user's computer.

**My question:**

How can I force the IE/safari to download the xml file like all other browsers?

Answer (score 2):

Its Browser property, you can't change its behavior. Its upon browser how it render the code.

Answer (score 0):

It will open in a new tab if you have the

```
target="_blank"
```

remove that and just use

```
<a href="test.xml">Click here</a>
```